# php file not uploading in folder

Tags: php, file-upload

I created an image url table of products and products table in database.
Registering image url and products in the database but not uploading the file.

this is php codes

```
$ekle = @$_POST['ekle'];
if(isset($ekle)){

$udyekle = $vt->prepare("INSERT INTO urunler(isim, 
fiyat,stok,detay,katid) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$udyekle->bind_param('siisi', $_POST['urunisim'], 
$_POST['urunfiyat'],
$_POST['urunstok'],
$_POST['urundetay'],
$_POST['urunkategori']);

$udyekle->execute(); 
$sonid = mysqli_insert_id($vt);

$udyekle->close();



$klasor="../images/product-details";
$dosya_sayi=count($_FILES['dosya']['name']); 

for($i=0;$i<=$dosya_sayi;$i++){ 
if(!empty($_FILES['dosya']['name'][$i])){ 
  $dosyaadi= sha1(md5($_FILES['dosya']['name'][$i]));
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['dosya']['tmp_name'][$i],$klasor."/".$dosyaadi)){
   echo "upload successful";
 }else{
  echo $_FILES['dosya']['error'];
 }

 $resup = $vt->prepare("INSERT INTO urunresim(urunid,url) VALUES (?, ?)");
  $resup->bind_param('is', $sonid,$dosyaadi);
 $resup->execute(); 
 $resup->close();

 } 
 }
 }
```

it gives error code 0

this is html codes. 
I added the name to the submit but something did not change

```
<form action="urunekle.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <label>Ürün ismini giriniz : </label>
                        <input class="form-control" name="urunisim"><br>
                         <label>Ürün fiyatını giriniz : </label>
                        <input class="form-control" name="urunfiyat"><br>
                         <label>Ürünün stok bilgisini giriniz : </label>
                        <input class="form-control" name="urunstok"><br>
                         <label>Ürün kategorisini seçiniz : </label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="sel1" name="urunkategori">
                          <?php 
                            $sorgucuk = mysqli_query($vt, "select * from kategoriler");
                            while($sonuccuk = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sorgucuk)){
                          ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $sonuccuk['id']; ?>"><?php echo $sonuccuk['isim']; ?></option>
                          <?php } ?>  
                        </select><br>
                        <label>Ürüne resim seçiniz : </label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="file" name="dosya" id="dosya" multiple="multiple" />
                         <label>Ürün hakkında detay giriniz : </label>
                        <textarea  class="form-control" name="urundetay"></textarea><br>
                        <input type="submit" name="ekle" id="ekle" value="Ekle" class="btn btn-success">
      </form>
```

Comment: Show us your html form

Comment: i added to html codes

Comment: is your other options work's fine ?

Comment: i don't know if it could be the cause but `<input class="form-control" type="file" name="dosya" id="dosya" multiple="multiple" />` should be `<input class="form-control" type="file" name="dosya[]" id="dosya" multiple="multiple" />` you missed brackets in the name

Comment: it is works thank you.